# QgsPrintLayout Scalebar does not update correctly

Tags: python, pyqgis, print-composer, layouts, scale-bar

With Pyqgis, I am trying to automate the creation of layouts using a template.
I use QGIS v3.32.2-Lima with Python v3.9.5.

In the template, I have a map item and a scalebar item.
The scalebar item looks like this :
[image]

Then, pyqgis loads that template and creates a new layout, with an updated map item.It has a different extent and a different scale.
I manage to refresh correctly the map extent.
However, the scalebar does not refresh correctly. It looks like this :
[image]

I tried to fix the scalebar item dimension (width 58 and height 19) with the method 'attemptResize'. It doesn't change anything.

What should I do to have the scalebar adapt to any extent/scale a user could choose ?